# Kor, Voq and the Blood Oath

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-discovery

Eighty-one years ago, three Klingons and Curzon Dax swore a blood oath to hunt down and kill the Albino, no matter what (for killing the warriors' first born sons).

So is Voq, an albino, the one they are hunting?  Has he has made an enemy of a Klingon by the name of Kor?  Is it possible these are the same people?

Comment: canon: uncertain if he is a Klingon - http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Albino

Comment: non-canon: he's a klingon: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Albino (and in non-canon he was a member of the house of Kor oddly enough)

Comment: There can be no answer to this question yet. The Albino is never given a canonical name, and as above, never canonically confirmed to be Klingon, although he certainly looks like he could be. _Star Trek: Discovery_ has not yet introduced Kor, Kang, or Koloth, let alone their children. All we have to go on right now is the coincidence that Voq is white-skinned, and that his chief adversary amongst the Klingons appears to be the leader of the house Kor will emerge from (but not Kor's father, whose name is canonically established as Rynar).

Comment: @NKCampbell - All signs point to him _not_ being a Klingon; ***The doors burst open from within -- and through the smoke, we see the ALBINO -- an all-white humanoid in good physical shape for a man of a hundred -- come rushing onto the balcony... people are yelling, scurrying about, confusion reigns... he is stunned -- and angry."*** - http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/439.txt. While the fact that he's described as "a humanoid" doesn't preclude him being a Klingon, it seems a very odd way to describe him

Answer (score 3):

**Arguments in favour of Voq being the Albino:**

1. The Albino is a Klingon according to the novels, and here is his story: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Qagh
2. Perhaps he's "The Albino, because at the end of all of this, he is stripped of EVERYTHING: Rank, whatever birthright he might have, even his damn name.  All because of high-bound Klingons. So he grows to hate them, and strikes out to punish the leaders of the great houses, using whatever tactics work, throwing Honor out the window with everything else, showing them how pitiful their honor really is.
3. There's no reason to refer to the DS9 character as "The Albino" except for the sake of the viewer - his appearance could have been, well, any Forehead of the Week alien we've seen on Trek.  But the writers specifically wanted us to know he was an albino.  And, his appearance is actually not dissimilar from a Klingon's.  There's nothing to really back this up officially, but I think it's not off the mark to speculate that The Albino is, in fact, a Klingon.
4. The speculation is, of course, that this insult from Kor's family, plus insults or at least allegiances between Kor, Kang, and Koloth, as well as events yet unseen in Discovery, and Kor, Kang, and Koloth's raid on The Albino's headquarters, lead Voq to attack Klingon colonies, and to poison the first born sons of Kor, Kang, and Koloth.

**Arguments against:**

1. The problem with your idea is that 10 years before TOS is about 30 years too early for the blood oath.
2. The Albino clearly despises Klingons - which means he either isn't one, collapsing this theory, or "Klingon" is not the designated term for their species, but for a culture.  As detailed in the Trekspertise Klingon History videos, there are mentions of other peoples on the Klingon homeworld not referred to as Klingons - the Fek'Ihri.

**Arguments that could go either way:**

1. The Albino is not painted in a very Klingon light in DS9.  He's referred to as a criminal overlord.  His use of language, and his disposition, is nothing like a typical Klingon's.  This appears, at first, to poke additional holes in the theory that The Albino was once Voq, however, Discovery leaves us a bit of an opening to allow this, through L'Rell.  She describes House Mo'Kai as "watchers," "deceivers," and "weavers of lies," tactics and concepts that would fit in more with a criminal overlord than an honorable Klingon warrior.  Additionally, L'Rell tells Voq that she can help him regain position, but that he must be willing to sacrifice everything.  So, it could be that Voq discards the Klingon culture after all of these events.

**Verdict**: Jury is out on this one.

*Full credit to* [NSMike87](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4O3Gyt8As5M&lc=Ugz8Di3ieEqryv8emUl4AaABAg), [TazG2000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4O3Gyt8As5M&lc=Ugz8Di3ieEqryv8emUl4AaABAg.8YZxAmCWjo58Yc2Ag0UtcS) and [lexxstrum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4O3Gyt8As5M&lc=Ugz8Di3ieEqryv8emUl4AaABAg.8YZxAmCWjo58YdPWHAGtMy).

Comment: Main argument against: Voq isn't an albino any more. In physical appearance, he's human.

Comment: Looks like my Theory may actually have truth to it. As the baby is they had is Albino and how it was taken away from its parents. I would be surprised if they didn't both die by the end of season 3. which would potentially set up the Blood Oath Story Arc. Also, the ongoing feud with House Kor in discovery...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the albino is indeed a Klingon, it is possible that Voq is the one Kor vowed to avenge, since we already know Kol is from the House of Kor. We can speculate that Kol's ongoing feud with Voq leads directly to the blood oath that Kor and Curzon Dax took.